# mongoose multi update in one query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

is there please any way to perform this query in mongoose?

this multi update is possible from mongodb v2.6

```
{
update: <collection>,
updates:
[
    { q: <query>, u: <update>, upsert: <boolean>, multi: <boolean> },
    { q: <query>, u: <update>, upsert: <boolean>, multi: <boolean> },
    { q: <query>, u: <update>, upsert: <boolean>, multi: <boolean> },
    ...
],
ordered: <boolean>,
writeConcern: { <write concern> }
}
```

i found this topic, but its pretty old: [Mongodb multi update with different value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512953/mongodb-multi-update-with-different-value)

thx everyone for suggetions

Comment: Can you give an example of the update you'd like so answerers can have a general idea of what you're expecting to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the details that you provided, I assume that you would like to issue a series of update queries based on several different criteria and specific update values for each particular query.

Nevertheless, I will address both possible scenarios when it comes to updating multiple documents in MongoDB.

As I previously mentioned, if you would like to update multiple documents, there are two possible scenarios:

- Update multiple documents that match one set of specific criteria, case in which you can use `db.collection.update()`, by specifying the `multi` parameter when you fire your operation [Official MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter)
- Use `bulk.find.update()` to chain several `multi update` operations and execute them in bulk [Official MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update)

Answer (score 0):

ok these are the results

```
var p_text_data = require("../public/import/p_100_k_text_cz.json"); //data with new vals
_und.map(p_text_data,function(vals,index) {

        var new_name = vals.name + something;

        e_textModel.collection.update({ 'id': vals.id }, { $set: { 'name': new_name } }, {upsert: false, multi: true}); 

});
```

using sinle update every iteration, updating 100k documents take about 7+ seconds

and next code, using bulk, take less than 3 seconds

```
var bulk = e_textModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
_und.map(p_text_data,function(vals,index) {
    ite++;

    var new_name = vals.name + something;

    bulk.find( { 'id': vals.id } ).update( { $set: { 'name': new_name } } );

});
bulk.execute();
```

**EDIT:**

```
$var bulk = e_textModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
```

is even couple times faster then UnorderedBulkOp in this case